# Using Dropdown values to set user ranks on creation

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have a user creation form in my Django web application. I am able to create a user normally.

I have a model in my application called user_type, which has the is_admin field, is_manager field and the user field linked to the User Foreign Key. I have added a dropdown in my user creation form to enable the Admin create a user and as well assign the user_type of the user using the dropdown.

I am now confused of how to grab the admin choice and enable the user_type depending on that.

models.py

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    # CUSTOM USER FIELDS
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    telephone = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/users/%i/" % (self.pk)

class user_type(models.Model):
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_manager = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        if self.is_manager == True:
            return User.get_email(self.user) + " - is_manager"
        else:
            return User.get_email(self.user) + " - is_admin"
```

views.py

```
def AddUser(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        telephone = request.POST.get('telephone')
        firstname = request.POST.get('firstname')
        lastname = request.POST.get('lastname')
        address = request.POST.get('address')
        zipcode = request.POST.get('zipcode')
        city = request.POST.get('city')
        region = request.POST.get('region')
        country = request.POST.get('country')
        password = User.objects.make_random_password()
        # is_manager = request.POST.get('is_manager')

        try:
            user = User.objects.create_user(email=email, telephone=telephone, firstname=firstname, password=password,
                lastname=lastname, address=address, zipcode=zipcode, city=city, country=country)

            user.send_welcome_mail(new_password)

            # if is_manager == True:
            #     user.user_type.is_manager == True
            # else:
            #     user.user_type.is_admin == True

            user.save()
            messages.success(request, "User Created Successfully!")
            return redirect('users')
        except Exception as e:
            messages.error(request, "Failed to Create User!" + str(e))
            return redirect('users')

    return render(request, "core/adduser.html")
```

adduser.html

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="telephone" placeholder="Telephone" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Firstname" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Lastname" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <select class="custom-select2 form-control" name="user_type" style="width: 100%; height: 38px;">
                    <optgroup label="Select User Type">
                        <option value="M" name="is_manager">Manager</option>
                        <option value="A" name="is_admin">Admin</option>
                    </optgroup>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address" class="form-control"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create User</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few changes to code style before explaining:

1. Rename `user_type` to `UserType` as it is suggested in Django Models.
2. Rename the view `AddUser` to `add_user` as it is suggested in PEP8 for function names.

In your `add_user` view:

```py
if request.method == "POST":
    # ...get your fields from the form
    user_type = request.POST.get("user_type")

    # ...create your user here

    # assign default values first
    is_admin = False
    is_manager = False

    # parse value from the form input
    if user_type == "M":
      is_manager = True
    elif user_type == "A":
      is_admin = True

    # now create 1-to-1 field
    user_type = UserType.objects.create(
        user=user, is_admin=is_admin, is_manager=is_manager
    )
```

Few more suggestions:

1. It is better to use `user = User.objects.get(email=email)` first to check if that user exists and handle that scenario. `.get()` function will give `User.DoesNotExist` exeption, handle that one for creating the user. Try to avoid generic `Exception` class as much as it is possible.
2. Use a [Model Form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/) for checking the input from the client, it will make sure that your inputs are good for the model requirements like required fields, field lengths and etc. before even trying to create that model.

Comment: I don't understand the last section where you made mention 2 few more suggestion. The model form for validation as well as the email verification. It's not clear to me. could you please make some illustration. Thanks

Comment: The first one is not about the email, just for checking if a user is already registered/exists using one of the unique values and assuming the email address is unique for users, it can be used here. Another option is to use the username or any other custom field. If the user already exists, you can notify the user in the form page that email with provided details already does exists.

Comment: Second suggestion is about using a Model Form (a form class based on `forms.ModelForm`) for your User. The form can be used to make creating your html form easier and the most important, it can be used in your view function to verify inputs from the user in the page. That will prevent things like harmful inputs (injections). The form provides a functionality to verify each input one-by-one and also all of them together. It will also provide information about issues related to the inputs in the page. Check the forms page in the link for more details, it is very useful feature.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i got it better now and will do more studies as reagrds that.